# Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'dtInventory_v10_r1' error in c#

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some code in c# that was converted over from vb.net.  I am getting this error on the codebehind page of an aspx page.  One of the errors reads

> Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'dtInventory_v10_r1'

the error that I am receiving from visual studio reads this however

> Argument missing

The line of code that this references is as follows:

```
objInv = objMan.GetInventoryObject(mInventory_ID, , , true);
```

The GetInventoryObject is written in VB and looks like this

```
Public Function GetInventoryObject(ByVal vInventory_ID As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal vVIN As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vSelectedTrim As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeDetail As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeValuations As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeEquipment As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeTitle As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeBuyersGuide As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeImages As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeFinance As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeExpenses As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeTransactions As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeInternetMarketing As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeFlags As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vIncludeSupportingFiles As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal vYearModel As Integer = 0, _
    Optional ByVal vMake As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vModel As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vBodyStyle As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vExtTrim As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vExtColor As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vIntColor As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vTransmission As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vDriveType As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vEngine As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vWeight As Integer = 0, _
    Optional ByVal vFuelType As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal vLot_ID As Integer = 0
    ) As Inventory

    Dim strParameters As String = ""
    Dim dsTempDataSet As DataSet
    Dim strXML As String = ""

    If vLot_ID = 0 Then
        'if an autosave occurs and a lot is not enterd 
        'pass in the uses branch
        vLot_ID = mobjSecurity.Branch_ID
    End If

    strParameters = "@SessionGUID='" & mobjSecurity.SecuritySession & "', "
    strParameters &= "@Inst_ID=" & mobjSecurity.Inst_ID.ToString & ", "
    strParameters += "@Inventory_ID=" & vInventory_ID.ToString & ", "
    strParameters += "@VIN='" & vVIN.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@IncludeDetail=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeDetail) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeValuations=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeValuations) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeEquipment=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeEquipment) & ","
    strParameters += "@IncludeTitle=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeTitle) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeBuyersGuide=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeBuyersGuide) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeImages=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeImages) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeFinance=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeFinance) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeExpenses=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeExpenses) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeTransactions=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeTransactions) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeInternetMarketing=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeInternetMarketing) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeFlags=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeFlags) & ", "
    strParameters += "@IncludeSupportingFiles=" & mobjFormat.FormatBooleanToInteger(vIncludeSupportingFiles) & ", "
    strParameters += "@YearModel=" & vYearModel.ToString & ", "
    strParameters += "@Make='" & vMake.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@Model='" & vModel.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@BodyStyle='" & vBodyStyle.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@ExtTrim='" & vExtTrim.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@ExtColor='" & vExtColor.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@IntColor='" & vIntColor.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@Transmission='" & vTransmission.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@DriveType='" & vDriveType.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@Engine='" & vEngine.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@Weight=" & vWeight.ToString & ", "
    strParameters += "@FuelType='" & vFuelType.ToString & "', "
    strParameters += "@Lot_ID=" & vLot_ID.ToString & " "

    dsTempDataSet = Fetch("pr_Inventory_v10_FetchObject_r1", strParameters, mobjSecurity.SQLDatabase)

    Dim dsComplete As New DataSet
    Dim objExport As New dtDataTools_v10_r1.ExportData

    Dim iTable As Integer = 0
    Dim sDataTableName As String = ""
    Dim sRelatedTableName As String = ""
    Dim sRelatedFieldName As String = ""

    '-- Loop all returned tables
    For iTable = 0 To dsTempDataSet.Tables.Count - 1
        If sDataTableName = "" Then
            '-- Make sure we have rows
            If dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                '-- Read first column... 
                If dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).Columns(0).ColumnName.ToLower = "datatablename" Then
                    '-- Get table info
                    sDataTableName = dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).Rows(0).Item("datatablename")
                    sRelatedTableName = dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).Rows(0).Item("RelatedTableName")
                    sRelatedFieldName = dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).Rows(0).Item("RelatedFieldName")
                End If
            End If
        Else
            '-- Name and store the table
            dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).TableName = sDataTableName
            dsComplete.Tables.Add(dsTempDataSet.Tables(iTable).Copy)
            Try

                '-- Add Relationship?
                If sRelatedTableName.Trim <> "" Then
                    With dsComplete
                        .Relations.Add("rel_" & sDataTableName, _
                            .Tables(sRelatedTableName).Columns(sRelatedFieldName), _
                            .Tables(sDataTableName).Columns(sRelatedFieldName))
                    End With
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            sDataTableName = "" '-- Reset
            sRelatedTableName = ""
            sRelatedFieldName = ""

        End If

    Next

    '-- Generate and strip the XML
    strXML = objExport.ConvertDatasetToXML(dsComplete.Copy, "dealtrace", MappingType.Attribute, 1)
    '-- Load XML into Report object
    Return LoadInventory_XML(strXML)

End Function
```

The mInventory_ID is an int variable and is declared like this

```
protected Int32 mInventory_ID = 0;
```

I am not sure how to fix the error that I am getting I have tried to change the parenthesis to square brackets to no avail.  I have tried adding extra commas for the remaining declarations in the function but that also yielded the same errors.

Are there any suggestions on what may be causing this error and how to fix this

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are optional parameters, and should be called with following syntax

```
objInv = objMan.GetInventoryObject(vVIN=mInventory_ID, vIncludeValuations=true);
```

Basically you explicitly name parameters default values of which you would like to override. Skipping param with `, ,` is indeed incorrect syntax.

Comment: This appears to work however the last statement "vIncludeValuations = true" thrown this error "Argument type 'bool' is not assignable to parameter type 'string' "  Should I put single quotes around true?

Comment: I fixed the remaining error by adding Convert.ToString to the vIncludeValuations